# How to get toolbox in Visual studio shell (F#)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I get toolbox in Visual Studio Shell when I am working with F#? Currently I have installed F# with Visual Studio integrated mode. I want to design GUI forms with toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a GUI designer for F#, especially considering the discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556510/is-f-a-usable-language-for-net-windows-development). But there are some tricky ways to make use of the GUI designer for C# as [this article](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/fsharp/html/how-to-use-form-designer-from-fsharp.html) shows.